# how to save a text file automatically in flex when the text area is changed/edited. please help me

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I had a situation like.... I need to save a text area field in the form of .text file automatically when ever the text area is changed/edited. Please some one help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In a Flex TextInput or TextArea you can use the [change event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/SkinnableTextBase.html#event%3achange) to detect when something has changed.  So, you'll probably want to use that to trigger your "save this text" code.

If you want to save things as a file on the server, then you can use that change event to trigger your service.

If you want to save things on the client machine, you may have more difficulty.

If you're dealing with an AIR application, you can save the file locally using the [File class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html).

In a browser based app; you cannot save files without user input.  So the location, and filename of the file is beyond your control.  Accessing that file at some future point also requires user input.

You may be able to store the value as a [shared object](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=lsos_5.html), which is in essence the Flex version of a cookie.